# 422 unprocessable entity error received from pastebin POST request

Tags: c#, .net, post, webrequest, pastebin

I've been making a big project recently and have been trying to figure out how to make my C# .Net program post a string to Pastebin and return the URL of the paste created. I've gotten a few lines of code down (not mine, I found it on this site) but even after much troubleshooting I always get some kind of error from it. I'm not familiar with webrequest or any of the similar methods designed to interact with the internet, so I had to rely on advice from other people online, yet even after multiple hours worth of searching online for solutions to my problem I still get a (422) unprocessable entity error from my code when run:

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php");
        //ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] bData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat("api_option=paste&api_paste_code=", Console.ReadLine(), "&paste_private=0&api_dev_key=" + api_dev_key));
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wr.ContentLength = bData.Length;
        Stream sMyStream = wr.GetRequestStream();
        sMyStream.Write(bData, 0, bData.Length);
        wr.GetResponse();
        sMyStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Exact error:

```
Run-time exception (line 36): The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.

Stack Trace:

[System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.]
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Program.Main() :line 36
```

I've decided the best course of action to take to solve my problem is just to get help directly from people who know this kind of stuff well. I've just been running this code on dotnetfiddle. If you need more information please ask.

Edits: updated a few parameters (such as api_option)

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look at [the docs](https://pastebin.com/doc_api) I think you're using a unsuitable parameter (`paste_subdomain`) for posting your API key.

Have a try using `api_dev_key` instead:

```
byte[] bData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat("paste_code=", encoded, "&paste_private=0&paste_expire_date=1D&api_dev_key=" + api_dev_key));
```

If this doesn't work, better have a look at the other parameters, too.

---

Just a blind guess, but probably the error occurs because you don't url-encode the code to be posted.

Maybe it'll do the trick if you encode the code entered:

```cs
var toBePosted = Console.ReadLine();
var encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(toBePosted);
byte[] bData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat("paste_code=", encoded, "&paste_private=0&paste_expire_date=1D&paste_subdomain=" + api_dev_key));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried your recommendation, but I still get the same error.

Comment: I tried substituting paste_subdomain with api_dev_key for both the old code and the code you suggested, but it still returns a (422) unprocessable entity error

Comment: Too bad  Did you check the other parameters as well?

Comment: I checked and api_option was another required parameter, and paste_code should be written as api_paste_code, yet it still doesn't work even after updating those parameters:

byte[] bData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat("api_option=paste&api_paste_code=", encoded, "&paste_private=0&paste_expire_date=1D&api_dev_key=" + api_dev_key));

Answer (score 1):

I've had working code for a while, and just recently got this error showing up on one of my bots that paste to pastebin.. worked fine @ 1230MST started erroring @ 100pm MST..

Could be something on their end, and nothing has changed here, and its worked for many years.

Comment: So some of your bots are working but not one specifically? If it's not too much to ask, can you send the code that previously worked for you, or post a Pastebin link to it?